# Hibernate 5 Native query support - Slow response generation

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, query-optimization

I am trying to fetch 1000 rows using the Hibernate createNativeQuery. The query contains two joins. When I execute the same in SQL developer I see that response comes up in less than 400 ms but from the code it takes 20 sec to get the result.

> Table
>
> Employee - id, name, country_id, dept_id
>
> Country - id, country_name, office_count,inflation_rate
>
> Dept - id, dept_name,manager

```
String queryStr = "Select e.id as id, e.name as empName, c.country_name AS countryName,
    d.dept_name AS deptName FROM  owner.Employee AS e LEFT OUTER JOIN owner.Country c
        ON e.country_id = c.id LEFT OUTER JOIN owner.Dept AS d ON e.country_id = d.id";

List<Object[]> rows  = this.getSession().createNativeQuery(queryStr).setMaxResults(1000)
    .addScalar( "id", StringType.INSTANCE )
    .addScalar( "empName", StringType.INSTANCE )
    .addScalar( "countryName", StringType.INSTANCE )
    .addScalar( "deptName", StringType.INSTANCE )
    .list();
```

What is the additional processing that Hibernate is doing that could be causing this delay ? Is there someway I could optimize the code ?

Comment: When executed in SQL Developer is the IDE returning all the rows or only the top N rows?  If the IDE is not retrieving all the rows it may not be a fair comparison.

Comment: Your data suggest following interpretation. To get the first 20 rows (one page of data) the elapsed time is 400ms. Lineary scaling to get all 1000 rows you need 20 seconds. And btw. you need 2 to 3 thousend index access in your query - if the index blocks are on the disc you get approximately 100 disc access per seconds, which is near your 20 seconds observation.

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing in your Hibernate code which alone would explain unusually slow performance.  The calls to `addScalar()` might slow things down slightly, but that should be minor.

If you want to make your query dramatically faster, then you need to think about tuning and optimization.  Here is one indexing strategy which should help:

```
CREATE INDEX country_idx ON Country (id, country_name);
CREATE INDEX dept_idx ON Dept (id, dept_name);
```

This strategy assumes that Oracle would do a full table scan on the `Employee` table. The above two indices would then allow for rapid lookup, for each record involved in the join.

Comment: Even without the Index the query is pretty fast when i run it from SQL developer. As per Hibernate documentation. "To avoid the overhead of using ResultSetMetadata, or simply to be more explicit in what is returned, one can use addScalar():"

Comment: Running a query directly against a database and running it from Java code aren't the same thing.  The latter situation means you potentially have to send large amounts of data across a network.